# Applescript Producing Error when Sending Messages

Tags: email, messages

I have this Applescript code that sends a message to a given contact. However, I get this runtime error:

```
Can’t get «class pres» "a_name@gmail.com" of application "Messages".
```

The important part of the code:

```
tell application "Messages"
    set theBuddy to buddy theName
    repeat theTimes times
        send theMessage to theBuddy
    end repeat
end tell
```

`theBuddy` is the email address, `theTimes` is the number of iterations, and `theMessage` is the message to be sent. So why is producing this error, and how do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Can't repro using that snippet. Working fine here. Are you using an email address as 'theName'? Should be a contact name, as listed in your address book, I'd think - like 'Fred Bloggs'

Comment: Can't reproduce either. Strange.

Comment: Were you perhaps (I don't assume you remember for sure, since this question is so old) attempting to also `log theBuddy` or similar?  I get this error when doing something similar and trying to log it...  Will post an answer if I figure that out.